# C# Google API - Invalid JSON payload received

Tags: c#, json, api, payload

I'm about to create a request to googles API, the purpose is the change the signature of a gmail account.

This is the part of the request that is triggering an error. If I change the 'signature' string to this 'Test', everything is woring fine. I know it must has something to do with the formatting I just can't seem to find the issue.

```
            string signature = "<div>Med venlig hilsen / regards,</div><div><br></div><div><strong>" + "Name" + "</strong></div>" +
                            "<div><em>" + "Role" + "</em></div>" +
                            "<div><a href=\"www.xxx.com/da/\"style=\"color:rgb(17,85,204);\"target=\"_blank\"><strong>xxxx xxxxx</strong></a></div>" +
                            "<div>Tel. " + "Phone" + "</div>" +
                            "<div>E-mail: <a href=\"mailto:" + "Mail" + "\"style=\"color:rgb(17,85,204);\"target=\"_blank\">" + "Mail" + "</a></div>" +
                            "<div><a href =\"www.xxx.com/da/\"style=\"color:rgb(17,85,204);\"target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"www.xxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/xxxxx-logo-7.png\"></a></div>" +
                            "<br></br><div>xxx<br> Reg.no. xxx- <a href =\"www.xxx.com/\"style=\"color:rgb(17,85,204);\"target=\"_blank\">www.xxx.com</a></div>";
```

The error is as follows:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected , or } after key:value pair.\n\u003cdiv\u003eMed venlig hils\n^",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected , or } after key:value pair.\n\u003cdiv\u003eMed venlig hils\n^",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "parseError"
          }
        ],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Means do you want to find out the error in your given Json?

Comment: @Sh.Imran That is the goal.

Comment: Back slashes `\\` are the issue in your Json. With `\\` Json not works properly. If you can remove this then it will work.

Comment: @Sh.Imran Thank you so much! In C# '\"' is used to define a '"' inside a string, so I didn't except that it would include that in the request. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Back slashes `\` are the issue in your Json. With `\` Json not works properly. If you can remove this then it will work.

Comment: @tac-o2 it will be appreciable if you tick mark the answer and you will receive some score as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sh.Imran for coming up with the solution

Back slashes ` are the issue in your Json. With ` Json not works properly. If you can remove this then it will work.

Comment: This is not the correct way to thanks. If you got useful help. Just accept and upvote for my answer will be appreciation.